# libdjvulibre21 failed installation/upgrade to version 11.10 of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, upgrade, libreoffice

While upgrading to Version 11.10 of Ubuntu, I noticed that the (aptitude) package `libdjvulibre21` failed installation. After instllation, I was prompted that one package had failed installation, and that I execute the Package Manager, or run `apt-get` to rectify this problem.  Running `apt-get` still did not resolve the problem.  Instead, it produced the following log file.

```
vasilios@vasilios-OptiPlex-210L:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for vasilios: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpanel-applet-4-0 libswscale0 libavutil50 libgcj-bc libcamd2.2.0
  linux-headers-2.6.38-8 libftgl2 kalgebra-common libpostproc51 libpari2-gmp
  libavformat52 libgcj11 kalgebra linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic
  gcj-4.5-jre-lib libsigsegv0 libavcodec52 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gcj-4.5-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdjvulibre21
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdjvulibre21
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/706 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 298010 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libdjvulibre21 3.5.23-3ubuntu2 (using .../libdjvulibre21_3.5.24-8_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdjvulibre21 ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:0>: data error'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libdjvulibre21_3.5.24-8_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdjvulibre21_3.5.24-8_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
vasilios@vasilios-OptiPlex-210L:~$
```

No matter how many times I execute `apt-get` I receive the same error messages.  Judging by this log file. it would appear that the `libdjvulibre21_3.5.24-8_i386.deb` package that was downloaded during the installation is broken.  Not sure how I can force a re-download using `apt-get`.

As an aside, this problem wouldn't have anything to do with the fact that I was trying to install OpenOffice under Ubuntu Version 11.04?  In this case, even though the installation was successful, the LibreOffice icons were still being displayed on the side-bar, and the OpenOffice package was nowhere to be found on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file `/var/cache/apt/archives/libdjvulibre21_3.5.24-8_i386.deb` and try again to install the package.